# How do I count the number of data in the same month in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I count the number of data of the same month? 
I've input the date values as VARCHAR2
Each month has at least more than 2 data.

This is the only way I know but I can't count a specific number. It only shows all. What if I only want the count of the month of JUNE?

```
select COUNT(COLUMN NAME)
from TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: "*date values as VARCHAR2*" why on earth did you do that? Never ever store dates (or numbers) as varchar columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Group By:

```
select MonthColumn, COUNT(COLUMN NAME) 
from TABLE_NAME 
group by MonthColumn
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(monthColumn)
FROM tableName
GROUP BY monthColumn
HAVING monthColumn = 'JUNE'
```